# Images which are shown in netbeans IDE are not shown in real app

Tags: java, image, netbeans, java-11

I developed an app with a GUI in java with the help  of netbeans (I'm using Apache netbeans 9 and JDK 11). Also I have added some images to that Frame. Those images are fine inside netbeans but I cannot see those images in real app which I run through command line.

So this is the way I added images to the app

```
JButton saveTxtTool = new JButton(new ImageIcon((getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString() + "morsecoder/save-text-large.png").replaceAll("file:/", "")));
```

Because of this problem I tried this line to get the path that is passed to the ImageIcon.

```
System.out.println(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString().replaceAll("file:/","")+"morsecoder/undo.png");
```

And this is the way I run the app without netbeans with the command prompt.

```
set Gantt_Generator_v5.0="C:\Program Files (x86)\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0"
start java -cp dist\MorseCoder.jar morsecoder.MorseCoder
```

After running the app in both IDE an CMD, these are the results I got.

```
//in netbeans IDE
C:/Users/Seniru/Documents/MorseCodeConverter/NetBeansProjects/MorseCoder/build/classes/morsecoder/undo.png

//in cmd
C:/Users/Seniru/Documents/MorseCodeConverter/NetBeansProjects/MorseCoder/dist/MorseCoder.jar/morsecoder/undo.png
```

> So I got that the paths are different after these test. So my question is how to solve this problem and what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: you can't just use a path like /.../dist/MorseCoder.jar/morsecoder/undo.png
you'll need to research on how to get the resources from within the jar file

Comment: You should work with resources - definitely not with files and dependencies on code source.

Comment: So how could I get the resources in the java file. I tried, but it didnt work. Are there any API to work with JAR files

Comment: **NetBeans 9 does not support the use of JDK 11**: NetBeans 9 only implemented ["Java 9 and 10 Support"](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/). Use a supported JDK and then update your post as appropriate.

Comment: @skomisa but I dont think it is a problem with netbeans or jdk - because it can run jdk11 classes too. I think it is a problem with the path

Comment: @SeniruPasan OK, understood. I can only repeat that if you choose to use a JDK version that is not supported by NetBeans then you should not be surprised if you get problems. Of course your specific problem might be unrelated to the use of JDK 11, but why invite the possibility? Are you doing anything that relies on JDK 11, and would not work with JDK10?